# Why does my OpenProcessing Sketch read inconsistent Pixel Values from Graphics Buffer?

Tags: graphics, buffer, p5.js

My OpenProcessing Game involves controlling a Player (rect), to draw a colored Trail as it moves.  The Trail is drawn on a separately created Graphics Buffer, using createGraphics().  The goal of the Game is paint as much of the Buffer as possible with the Player's Color.

After a specified amount of time, the Program will stop the Game and load up the pixel Array from that Graphics Buffer, and calculate the Player's Score.

Whenever I reload/run my Game, I get inconsistent values for the Score.  Even if I don't move the Player, I get random Score values.  I expect the Score to be 0, but sometimes it displays 961 or another number.

I am not sure if I am using loadPixels() incorrectly, or my Algorithm for calculating the Score is off.

Here is a link to my OpenProcessing Sketch.

https://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/825667

Answer (score 0):

In your sketch you're calling `trail.drawPixels()` before you actually want to load the pixels.

You want something like this:

```
if (timeElapsed >= 5) {
    trail.loadPixels() // draw the pixels at the point you want to calculate the score
    for (let i = 0; i < 4 * (width * height / 2); i += 4) {
        //Condition to check if matching Player Colors (color(0, 255, 255))
        if (trail.pixels[i] == 0 && trail.pixels[i + 1] == 255 && trail.pixels[i + 2] == 255)
            player1Score += 1;
    }
    displayScore();
    noLoop();
}
```

Comment: I updated the sketch ( put call of loadPixels() inside condition, instead of continuous calls to it inside draw() ) with your suggested code, but there is still inconsistency in the Score value.

Comment: What is strange though is that if I remove the Player (Class Instance) from the Program, the Score stays at 0 (after running the Game about 10 times).

Comment: Likely there is an issue with how you're adding up the pixels, this will help https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/get